# VueJs Disable PayPal Button with checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, iframe, paypal

I'm trying to disable the paypal button in VueJs by using JavaScript native
So, when the paypal iframe was loaded, i'm trying to do it like this :

```
methods: {
    async initPaypal() {
      this.$store.dispatch('app/clearMessage')
      this.isLoading = true

      try {
        const { payments } = await paymentService.getPaymentContext(this.group)
        const widgetParameters =
          payments[payments.length - 1]?.additionalDatas?.PAYMENT_WIDGET_INFORMATION.widgetParameters

        if (widgetParameters) {
          this.client = new adeocookie.CookiePgwClient(widgetParameters, 'paypal-container')

          this.client.initialize().then(() => {
            console.log('loaded')
            this.client.render()
            this.isLoading = false
            // to disable button
            const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]
            iframe.style.pointerEvents = 'none'
          })
```

But it doesn't work
I've tried to display in console if the iframe was loaded and it's Ok

So, how can i disable this  iframe and ideally just the div that contains the button role ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rethink what you're doing. With the current PayPal JS SDK, there is no reason to be checking for iframes. If you need to disable the buttons when they are initialized, you can either have their div container start hidden (display:none) by simply coding it to start as such before any button code executes, or instead of hiding use the buttons' own method of `actions.disable()` (which does *not* hide) from `onInit`, as documented in [Validate user input](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/customize/validate-user-input/).

Here is an example of delayed render with display:none ...

```
<div id="paypal-button-container"></div>

<script>
   document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container')
     .style.display = 'none';

   paypal.Buttons().render('#paypal-button-container');

   document.querySelector('#myRadioField')
     .addEventListener('click', function() {
       document.querySelector('#paypal-button-container')
         .style.display = 'block';
     });
</script>
```

Comment: We are using an internal library , so we can't use the code directly from paypal api.
The solution that i've found is to add the css property pointer-event to none